# Foreign key always being set to null on database

Tags: django-models

I have the following `Model`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='parent_msg', null=True)
    (...)
```

And I do the following to create a new message:

```
(...)
parent_msg = Message.objects.get(id = message_id)
m = Message(..., parent = parent_msg)
m.save()
```

But the `parent_id` field is always being set to `NULL` on the database.

The documentation says "If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database," but I know `parent_msg` is not empty, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add `blank=True` to the `ForeignKey` parameters. Just in case, are you sure that all schema migrations were triggered? Also, are you sure you're not forgetting to save the object after initializing it? You can also try to set the parent as an attribute (not in the constructor:

`m.parent = parent_msg; m.save()`

Comment: I already tried adding `blank=True, default=None`, and I ran `syncdb`, and I also do `m.save()`. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with model definition. But with insertion code. 
can you please post complete code so that it can be verified. And what version of django are you using.

Comment: The problem was in a different part of the code. It works when I save `parent_msg` as you suggested. I'll mark the question as answered. Can you please roll back your last edit, so people know the right way to do it?

Comment: If the error was in some other part of the code. Then the code in the question will work without any problem. The code I provided was not needed.